# How to see lock messages on TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, locking, tortoisesvn

I can write a message when placing a lock on a file, using **TortoiseSVN**.  I can then use the *Repository Browser* to see that the file is locked.  It even shows a column with the programmer who locked the file.  But where can I see the message left when the file was locked?

The *Show Log* option in the *Repository Browser* does not even include them moments where a file has been locked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the "Check for modifications" dialogue on your working copy. Click "Check repository" to obtain fresh data.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.
But I does not feel natural.  Having to check out a working copy so I can then see if the reason some one locked a file?

Comment: You're probably right. I suppose that file locking is not a commonly used feature and could still use some polish.

Comment: Also this method seems not very good for seeing multi-line lock comments.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about TortoiseSVN, but

```
svn info url/to/file
```

shows lock details with the comment

Comment: That one I know.  Thanks.  But I needed to find out with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: With explicit revision argument:
svn info -r HEAD url/to/file
gets a bit more data